# Date issue in sql

Tags: sql

I have a table that I am entering data into every day. But I don't want that this data to be modified by other users. So I am backing up this data to another table using:

```
INSERT INTO  tbl_cancel_backup 
  SELECT tbl_cancel.[cdate] AS 'cdate',
         tbl_cancel.[machine_no] As 'No', 
         Sum(tbl_cancel.[amount]) AS 'Total' 
    FROM tbl_cancel 
   WHERE tbl_cancel.[Cdate]=@canceldate 
GROUP BY tbl_cancel.[Machine_no], tbl_cancel.[cdate];
```

After this operation, I would like to delete records which are 2 days earlier. How I have to modify below code to proper working one?

```
DELETE FROM tbl_cancel WHERE cdate = CONVERT (date, GETDATE()-2);
```

Thanks to everyone.

Comment: For what database?  I ask because SQL stands for "Structured Query Language", not "Standardized Query Language"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use `DateAdd` T-SQL

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx

`DELETE FROM tbl_cancel WHERE cdate <= DATEADD(d, -2, GETDATE())`

Comment: answered with only the link after I'd already posted the sql, then pasted the exact same sql in after that...and getting more votes...well played

Comment: @kekekela - Actually I posted first but it changed my posted date when I updated it.  I didn't steal your answer!

Comment: Yeah, because my SQL is the exactly the same as your SQL and I've never done a DATEADD in 10 years of consulting!  That is what happened, yeah!  I didn't copy your stupid SQL! Get a life dude!

Answer (score 1):

delete from tbl_cancel where cdate <= dateadd(d,-2,getdate())

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the [DATEADD](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx) syntax:

```
DELETE FROM tbl_cancel WHERE cdate <= CONVERT (date, DATEADD(dd,-2,GETDATE());
```